# Why did pork tenderloin go pink in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, pork

I cooked a pork tenderloin to at least 165 degrees F, maybe 180. The thermometer was in a pretty thick part of the meat and it was pretty much grey. Two days later it is pink in parts inside. I was wondering if this is an effect of cooling. I could reheat it in the microwave to 165 degrees but don't know if that is necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pork does tend to turn pink after refrigeration. The FDA changed the safe pork temperature to 145 degrees. If you take it out at 135 degrees it should be fine after sitting a few minutes. Especially with dry cuts like tenderloin, this will work wonders for juiciness! Yes, and it will be a bit pink in the middle and you don't need to reheat it.